# Why does numpy.logical_and create a singleton dimension in this example?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I stumbled upon something that seems a bit strange to me.
Consider the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(6,7)
print(a.shape)

b = np.logical_and([a <= 1], [a >= 0])
print(b.shape)
```

While I can easily get rid of the singleton dimension of b with numpy.squeeze, I wonder why it even appears at all.

According the the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) it says:

> Returns:
>
> y : ndarray or bool
>
> ```
> Boolean result with the same shape as x1 and x2 of the logical AND operation on corresponding elements of x1 and x2
> ```

But the shape of a and b are not the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Lose the parentheses there. The singleton dims appears because under the hoods NumPy converts the input to arrays with : `np.asarray([a<= 1])` and its `shape` is (1,6,7) here.

Comment: Group () are needed in the operator equivalent, `b = (a<=1) & (a>=0)`.  They would be ok in this function version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding a dimension when you put the boolean arrays in lists using square brackets:

```
[a <= 1]
```

Note:

```
In [10]: np.array([a <= 1])
Out[10]:
array([[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)

In [11]: np.array([a <= 1]).shape
Out[11]: (1, 6, 7)
```

Just use:

```
b = np.logical_and(a <= 1, a >= 0)
```

Comment: Ah, silly me! I did not take into account that you should only use brackets when necessary. I will keep this in mind. Thank you.